# Changing Background of selected text in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am currently using a RichTextBox for user editing, but I want to prevent selection unless a certain condition is met. I currently use the SelectionStart property of the text-box to deselect everything, but when the user drags his/her mouse while holding the left mouse button, the text flickers in blue.

Can i change the background color of the selection so that it is invisible?

EDIT: To clarify : What i am trying to create is my own implementation of the Windows CMD ( Just for fun ), and what i need to do is implement a CMD-like selection system

The code is located at [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/coderpro1123211/Terminal/blob/master/TerminalWINF/)

Comment: What did you try? anything??

Comment: Try to set `IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False"` on your RicheTextBox, if that achieves the desired result, you'll just have to bind these properties to your conditions

Comment: My problem is that when i try to select the text it flashes blue because the code does not deselect the text immediatley, so i want to make the selection back color black ( the BG color of the text box ) so that the selection does not show up, but i still want the user to be able to insert text, Like the Windows CMD works

Comment: so, show your code? as it stands it sounds like you've made simple errors

Comment: My code is at https://github.com/coderpro1123211/Terminal/tree/master/TerminalWINF

Comment: @Bug: Or it is simply impossible. This `private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 0 && richTextBox1.SelectedText[0]!='L')
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        }` produces exactly the described result.

Comment: What's the context here? Have you considered the UX implications of this feature? Some people repeatedly select and deselect text as part of their normal reading process.

Comment: @TaW That is almost exactly what i am trying, but the selected text flashes blue